# HTML5 input types and the asp.net MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

Im looking to make the editor templates in my MVC application use HTML5 input types.   The framework seems to get about 80% of the way there but there are a couple of things I can't seem to make happen (step values on numerics, placeholders, URL inputs, etc).

I'm sure that quite a bit of this is just me not knowing where to look, but

1. Is there a definitive list of what attributes I can use on View Models to provide the metadata used to generate the html?
2. Does anyone know of a project / nuget package that helps with this?  I'm not opposed to writing something, but would rather use something that's already been tried and tested.  Dean Hume's ASP.net [MVC HTML5 Helpers Toolkit](http://mvchtml5.codeplex.com/) is close, but I'd like to put as much information in the attributes as possible and let the runtime do the work via Html.EditorFor (just a personal preference).

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2010/10/21/integrate-html5-form-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx
See if it can help you get started.